# Add header and footer for every pages printed

Tags: files

I've used print module version 7.x-2.0. I've used pdf-version and print-friendly-version.

Now i want to do two different things. That is,

- Is it possible to add separate CSS for pdf, html or email templates like: print-pdf.css, print-html.css, print-email.css, print.css.?
- I have added header and footer. It only works for first page and last page, But I want to display them for every printed pages. How can I do that?

Comment: i also want same functionality. header and footer should display in each page. is any update on it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it to inset html tag in header ot footer file in tpl.php

```
<div class="header_print">enter your header </div>
print $content of your page 
<div class="footer_print">enter your footer</div>


<style type="text/css">

    .Footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    .Header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }

</style>
```

Comment: It is not working as i expected

Comment: I know this method works for dompdf, but then you must make sure the classes match (not `header_print` and `Header `). Also you might want to add a width of 100% or specify `left: 0; right: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the css only solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document

The reports say that it does not work on all browsers maybe support is better nowadays with some of the NEWER answers.